# Bind Glassfish to specific IP?

Tags: web-applications, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have the Glassfish 3.1 installed on machine that has 2 IP , I want to bind the Glassfish to one IP and make it listen to this IP only ,so the service can be accessed only through this IP , currently It can be accessed using the 2 Ips ?

Answer (score 0):

By default the network listeners listen to 0.0.0.0 (all network interfaces).  You can change this on a config-by-config basis.

In the navigation tree, go to Configurations->server-config->NetworkConfig->NetworkListeners->http-listener1

On that page you can change the IP from 0.0.0.0 to whatever you want.

Of course, you can change "server-config" to whatever configuration you want.  You can also choose the http listener you want to update (or create a new one).

For more info, check out the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggnfu.html#gjkwt).

Comment: This will just change the network listeners. Glassfish opens a plethora of other ports on 0.0.0.0 (e.g., for the thread pool). Even by searching every occurrence of 0.0.0.0 in domain.xml and every mention of "port" without an address and adding the correct IP there are still listeners on 0.0.0.0 once Glassfish (3.1.2) is started.

Comment: More than a year later, and now I'm running into this problem too, with no answer.
In my case, I need to start two GF servers, each on their own IP address (eg. 127.0.0.2 and 127.0.0.3).
I'm seeing GF4 bind to ports 8686, 4848, 3700, 8181, 7676, and 8080.
Also, using an variable in the address attribute doesn't appear to work, or rather, a defined assignment in asenv.conf doesn't get picked up. Tons of loose end in the whole configuration department.